# why the "php" does not change the html page color?

Tags: php, html

I tried to change the color of the page via php via this code, but it did not work for me, so what is wrong with it?
I tried a lot in it but it did not work for me so I went to the question here and I hope you help me and thank you

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $color = $_POST['color'];
   setcookie('backgroundColor',$color,18000,'/','',false,false);
  }



  function firstFun(){
   if (isset($_COOKIE['backgroundColor'])) {
    $color = $_COOKIE['backgroundColor'];
    echo $color;
   }else{
    $color = 'BLACK';
    echo $color ;
   }
  }

  function visibility(){
   if (isset($_COOKIE['backgroundColor'])) {
    return 'hidden';
   }else{
    return 'visible';
   }
  }


  ?>

  <html>
  
  <head></head>
  
  <body style='background-color : <?php print firstFun(); ?>'>

   <form action="" method="post" style="visibility: <?php  visibility();?>">
    <input type="color" name="color" placeholder="Please enter your color" style="margin: 5px;">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color: red; border: none;
    padding: 5px ; margin: 5px;"  >
   </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need 2 changes : 1_cookie time and 2_refresh page
Note: Without refresh the color will be visible only after second submit !

```
<?php
//echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //2_refresh
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        $color = $_POST['color'];
        //setcookie('backgroundColor',$color,18000,'/','',false,false);
        //1_cookie time
        setcookie("backgroundColor", $color, time()+3600); 
        //echo $_COOKIE['backgroundColor'];
    }

    //no changes
    function firstFun(){
        if (isset($_COOKIE['backgroundColor'])) {
            $color = $_COOKIE['backgroundColor'];
            echo $color;
        }else{
            $color = 'white';
            echo $color ;
        }
    }

    function visibility(){
        if (isset($_COOKIE['backgroundColor'])) {
            return 'hidden';
        }else{
            return 'visible';
        }
    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>test</head>
    <body style='background-color : <?php print firstFun(); ?>'>

        <form   id="myform" action="" method="post" style="visibility: <?php  visibility();?>">
            <input type="color" name="color" placeholder="Please enter your color" style="margin: 5px;">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color: red; border: none;
            padding: 5px ; margin: 5px;"  >
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and made some changes to it. 
You have to add time() to your cookie to tell till when the cookie is valid. I also removed your functions.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $cookie_value = $_POST['color'];
  $cookie_name = "backgroundColor";
  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 18000, '/', '', false, false);
}

// Set default color to black
$color = 'BLACK';
if (isset($_COOKIE['backgroundColor'])) {
  // If cookie exist, overwrite default color
  $color = $_COOKIE['backgroundColor'];
}

// Same as color, set default and overwrite when cookie exist
$vissible = "vissible";
if (isset($_COOKIE['backgroundColor'])) {
  $vissible = 'hidden';
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style='background-color : <?= $color; // <?= is a short way of echo ?>'>
<form action="" method="post" style="visibility: <?= $vissible; ?>">
  <input type="color" name="color" placeholder="Please enter your color" style="margin: 5px;">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color: red; border: none;
                padding: 5px ; margin: 5px;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```